# Configuring SQL Server 2005 with both server replication and client replication

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I need to set up this scenario:

> A SQL Server 2005 database will create a transactional replication subscription from another database to populate a set of lookup tables. These lookup tables will then be published as a merge replication publication to the client's SQL Server Mobile.

I remember seeing a similar scenario defined in the SQL Server Books Online somewhere, but I was unable to find the link anymore. I hope someone can help me find it, or otherwise point me to any other similar links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get the answers I needed at the [MSDN SQL Server Replication forum](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4093478&SiteID=1&mode=1).
The article I was looking for is called: [Republishing Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152553(SQL.90).aspx).

Apparently, it is located within "**Advanced Replication Features and Internals**" of the "**Configuring and Maintaining Replications**" section. It's a little non-obvious, so I spent most of my time looking in the "**Replicating Data Between a Server and Clients**" section, instead of there. Good to know, as there seems to be a number of other special scenarios worth looking at in there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get the interest of having a transactional replication to generate lookup tables. Such tables are not made to be updated from the client side, so why do you want to combine transactional + merge replication when you don't have the data modified by the subscribers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the original scenario is not clear, so let me clarify.

The database where the original lookup tables are located either remotely with bad network connection, or operated under heavy load. This approach was suggested so that the lookup tables are replicated to another database which all merge replication with the clients will be performed.

Of course, it may not be the most appropriate approach to our problem, so if anyone has a better idea, we'll like to hear them.

Still, the main reason for this question is to find an article I previously found (but stupidly did not bookmarked) which described our scenario quite well. Any possible leads to this article (title, author, similar topics, etc) are definitely appreciated.